# SparkSQL parsing - SqlBase.g4 doesn't recognize lowercase keyword and identifiers

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, antlr

I downloaded SqlBase.g4 and use the antlr v4 tool to build the lexer and parser. However, when I run the parser against a very simple query: `select * from table1` , it can't recognize the lowercase `select` and lowercase table identifier `table1`, when I change the query to `SELECT * FROM TABLE1` it works.

Is there a way to let the parser work for the lowercase scenario?

Answer (score 3):

You have two options here:

**1.** Build lexical rules that match either upper or lower case.

**2.** Build lexical rules that match keywords in all uppercase and then parse with a custom character stream that converts all characters to uppercase before sending them to the lexer (via the LA() method).

Read this article to get more information: [Case-Insensitive Lexing](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/case-insensitive-lexing.md)